# How to add datasource from a datatable to a dropdownlist with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim dt As DataTable = tbport()
    cbosearch.DataSource = dt
    cbosearch.DataValueField = "portCode"
    cbosearch.DataTextField = "portName"
    cbosearch.DataBind()


End Sub

Private Function tbport() As DataTable

    Dim dtport As New DataTable


    dtPort.Columns.Add("portCode")
    dtPort.Columns.Add("portId")
    dtPort.Columns.Add("portName")

    dtPort.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David")
    dtPort.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam")
    dtPort.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff")
    dtPort.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet")
    dtPort.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie")
    Return dtPort


End Function
```

I have a datatable with 70000 rows which is a static data. When i try to add data like above mentioned method it takes more time to find a certain row. how to create a javascript function to find out a row of data by means of value entered in dropdownlist?

Comment: What is `cboSearch` element in your code?  Is it some special third-party control or `asp dropdown` or `html select`?

Comment: you can use **ajax** for that. Use **ajax** in aspx page and call that **data** in vb page and **bind** it.